how to interrupt multicolumn environment, insert a table and restart it
On my las project I've the body of document developed on a multicolon (3) environment.
I need to break it (i.e. to insert a table that is wide spread and then finish the page continuing the 3 column environment.
Is it possible?
Can I momently breack the 3 column environment, insert the wide table  and then restart it? as to continue the 3 column?
this is my example:
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

 %-------------riga a-----I box--------------
   \newcommand{\TaI}{ TITLE 1 }
   \newcommand{\AaI}{aut 1}
    \newcommand{\ARTaI}{\lipsum[1] }
    \def\tmp#1.#2\tmp{#1}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\MaI\expandafter{\expandafter\tmp\ARTaI\tmp}
    %-----------riga a----II box-----
    \newcommand{\TaII}{  TITLE 2  }
    \newcommand{\AaII}{ aut 2}
    \newcommand{\ARTaII}{\lipsum[2]  }
     \def\tmp#1.#2\tmp{#1}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\MaII\expandafter{\expandafter\tmp\ARTaII\tmp}
    %----------riga a---III box-------
    \newcommand{\TaIII}{  TITLE 3  }
    \newcommand{\AaIII}{ auth 3}
    \newcommand{\ARTaIII} {\lipsum[3] }

\begin{document}%-----begin document -----------------
    \begin{multicols}{3}
 \textbf{\TaI\\
 \AaI\\}
 \ARTaI
 \\
\textbf{ \TaII
 \AaII\\}
 \ARTaII
\\
\textbf{ \TaIII
 \AaIII\\}
 \ARTaIII
    \end{multicols}

\end{document}


\end{mulicols}\begin{tabular}{<whatever>}<contents>\end{tabular}\begin{multicols}?

ok, it works! answer the question with this comment! I will vote it!

couldn't you have tried that without asking? It literally does what you say in the title, stops multicolumn, does something then starts multicolumn again.

I post myself some problems. I didn’t think that column restart from the place where they were interrupted and so on...

Please note that your document contains many manual formatting instructions for what seems like should be sectioning commands. Also note that you should almost never need to use \\  in normal text.

Nothing stops you from simply ending the multicols environment, placing arbitrary contents in full width, and then starting another multicols.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}%-----begin document -----------------
\begin{multicols}{3}
  \blindduck[1-3]
\end{multicols}
\begin{tabular}{llllllll}
  \hline
  Some & table & put & here & to & illustrate & the & effect \\
  Some & table & put & here & to & illustrate & the & effect \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{multicols}{3}
  \blindduck[1-3]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}


